# Unresolved Dependencies when building play 2.0 project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Downloaded play-2.0 from type safe yesterday, following instructions as far as I can, but when I come to build with sbt I get unresolved dependency errors:

> [warn]    :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: configuration not found in
>   org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: 'compile'. It was required from
>   org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;4.2.0.Final compile [warn]  ::
>   commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: configuration not found in
>   commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: 'compile'. It was required from
>   org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.2 compile [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [error]
>   {file:/Users/george/work/play/gbraw/}gbraw/*:update:
>   sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: configuration not found in
>   org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: 'compile'. It was required from
>   org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;4.2.0.Final compile [error]
>   unresolved dependency: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: configuration
>   not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: 'compile'. It was
>   required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.2 compile

I have deleted my .sbt directory (from an earlier install of sbt) but no joy. I'm sure I have something lying around that I shouldn't have but I'd appreciate any guidance on where to look...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `~/.ivy2/` folder? That's where the libraries are cached.

Comment: Perfect thank you... I removed the .m2 directory but had forgotten about .ivy2. Works a treat now!

Comment: though I've done this about three times now, removing the ivy cache directory - is there maybe an underlying problem here?

Comment: I have the same problem, I just downloaded play-2.0, created a project (play new todo) and inside the project folder called "play dependencies". There is still a problem with org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 which is "Evicted by 1.6.4" and I absolutely don't know how to solve this dependency...

Comment: Deleting .ivy2 did the trick for me, but why does this happen? Is there a less brute-force way to do this?

Answer (score 17):

so there is a problem with .ivy2 repository

as for *commons-codec-1.4*
there are *ivy-1.4.xml* and *ivydata-1.4.properties* files
in **${ivy_home}/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec** dir
but **NO** real *commons-codec-1.4.jar* in */jars* subdir
DELETE these *.xml* and *.properties* files and compile your project with sbt once again
dependency should fetch now

the same is for *slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar*