# Unresolved Dependencies for a new play 2.0 scala project

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, sbt, slf4j

Good day,

After "`play new todo`" (new scala project) -> "`cd todo`" -> "`play dependencies`" I get this one unresolved dependency "**org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1** required by "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.5.0, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final, play:play_2.9.1:2.0" reason "**Evicted by 1.6.4**".

Actually there is already **org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4** in resolved dependencies.

I tried different things, nothing worked. It seems that in the internets there is only one guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701866/unresolved-dependencies-when-building-play-2-0-project) who have the same problem, but the way he solved it didn't work for me.

I also tried the version of play framework that is in the AUR repository (I'm using Archlinux), but then I had other, even more complicated, problems, so I returned to the version downloaded from the official site.

Do anyone have any hint about how to solve this dependency problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states, "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1" is required.

You have "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4", which is, of course, not the same (i.e. 1.6.1 is not 1.6.4)

Cheers

Comment: Well, yes, I understood, it also says "Evicted by 1.6.4". The problem is that it's a vanila project that _already_ have an unresolved dependency that I dont know how to solve.

Comment: ah, did not notice, the "evicted by 1.6.4" bit. Sounds like a bug if play grabbed slf4j 1.6.4; otherwise, blow away 1.6.4 and replace with v.1.6.1 and see if the test project compiles

Comment: I replaced 1.6.4 (in context of the slf4j) by 1.6.1, cleaned Everything and now it is 1.6.4 and 1.6.2 that are evicted by 1.6.1 (so I have 2 dependencies unresolved)...

Comment: completely bizarre, where did 1.6.2 come from?? Not sure if this will help, but in some cases blowing away ~/.ivy2, ~/m2, followed by an "sbt clean update reload" can resolve dependencies issues. Otherwise, play mailing list, or bug tracker may be your next moves.

Comment: I found an answer in the mailing list 
"this is the marvelous world of transitive deps :D
as you can see, this is not really a problem but just a version eviction."

Thanks for your hints