# Dependency error with slf4j-api;1.6.1

Tags: playframework-2.0, slf4j

I got a sample of facebook connection and I tried to figure it out on it.
I over covered this folder as soon as I made new project.
And I even over covered the sample of facebook folder on after tutorial folder.

Every 3 of project, I've done to figure out the problem.

I changed every written version to 1.6.1 by myself 
and I consoled "sbt clean update reload" but it didn't work

So after that I found some solution, but not for me on this page
"[Unresolved Dependencies for a new play 2.0 scala project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989449/unresolved-dependencies-for-a-new-play-2-0-scala-project)"

**Virtualeyes**  said

'blowing away ~/.ivy2, ~/m2'

But I couldn't find 2 of them at all.

```
c:\play\connect>sbt clean update reload

c:\play\connect>set SCRIPT_DIR=C:\play\

c:\play\connect>java -Xmx512M -jar "C:\play\sbt-launch.jar" clean update reload

[info] Loading project definition from C:\play\connect\project
[info] Set current project to FacebookConnectTestUsingPlay2 (in build file:/C:/p
lay/connect/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2012. 11. 10 오전 6:07:50
[info] Updating {file:/C:/play/connect/}FacebookConnectTestUsingPlay2...
[info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Fin

[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j
-api;1.6.1: 'compile'. It was required from org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;4.
2.0.Final compile
[warn]  :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: configuration not found in commons-c
odec#commons-codec;1.4: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponent
s#httpclient;4.1.2 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/C:/play/connect/}FacebookConnectTestUsingPlay2/*:update: sbt.Reso
lveException: unresolved dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: configuration no
t found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1: 'compile'. It was required from org.hibern
ate#hibernate-validator;4.2.0.Final compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: configuration no
t found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4: 'compile'. It was required from org.
apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.1.2 compile
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed 2012. 11. 10 오전 6:08:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by myself again.

Based on the sample which is from

https://github.com/pawank/Facebook-Integration-in-Play-2.0-using-scribe-library

(because it was for version Play 2.0 not 2.0.4)

1.At **plugins.sbt**
Change to **addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")**

2.At **build.properties**
Change to **sbt.version=0.11.3**

1. Type **sbt**
2. Type **play**
3. Type **compile**(in play console)
4. if you have toubles with "**commons-codec**" and "**org.slf4j**" then erase every files in 
   C:\play**repository\local\org.slf4j** and C:\play**repository\local\commons-codec**
5. Type **'sbt clean update reload**' then **'play compile**'
6. it's gonna work

(dont' forget the changing which in **Application.scala**

```
lazy val config = play.Play.application().configuration()
    val FBAppId = config.getString("fb.app.id")
    val FBAppSecret = config.getString("fb.app.secretkey")
    val FBAppCallback = config.getString("fb.app.callback")
```

)
like i said that source is for version 2.0 not recently one