# Play 2.0.1: Module problems when i want to use it

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to use the Authentication and Authorization module for play 2.0.
I follow these instructions to 
[install it](https://github.com/t2v/play20-auth/blob/master/README.md).

But when I launch my app i have this error :

```
not found: type AuthConfig
```

So I don't know if the error are in my configuration or in the module.
Do you have an idea when i have to look to resolve this error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you properly import the AuthConfig trait ? (`import jp.t2v.lab.play20.auth.AuthConfig`)

Comment: yes i import all the classes : import jp.t2v.lab.play20.auth._ but the compiler say :
can not found object jp

I don't understand, sbt downloads the package but it seem play doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more research i found a solution for this problem 
Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701866/unresolved-dependencies-when-building-play-2-0-project)

I delete the repository of jp.t2v and it compiles!

Now i have a runtime error on this plugin but that's another question.